# import runs all code from module instead of just the imported function

Tags: node.js

This is my index.js file, located in the ./src directory:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

import CharacterDAO from "./dao/character";
import GearDAO from "./dao/gear";

import { startServer } from "./server";
import { seedData } from "./dataSeed";

// connect mongoDb, seed data if needed, run fastify server
export const runServer = async ({ dbUrl, dbName, environment, port }) => {
  // test seed data when starting server if running a test suite
  if (environment === "test") {
    await seedData({
      hostUrl: dbUrl,
      databaseName: dbName
    });
  }

  await MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, {
    poolSize: 50,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    wtimeout: 2500
  })
    .then(async conn => {
      const database = await conn.db(dbName);
      // inject database connection into DAO objects
      CharacterDAO.injectDB(database);
      GearDAO.injectDB(database);
      // start the fastify server
      startServer(port);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.stack);
      // process.exit(1);
    });
};

const serverArguments = process.argv.slice(2).map(arg => {
  return arg.split("=")[1];
});

const serverOptions = {
  dbUrl: serverArguments[0],
  dbName: serverArguments[1],
  environment: serverArguments[2],
  port: serverArguments[3]
};

runServer({
  ...serverOptions
});
```

jestconfig.json

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
}
```

Test script from package.json used to run the test (db credentials are omitted)

```
"test": "dbUrl=mongodb+srv://sdaw-dsawdad-dsadsawd@cluster0-jopi5.mongodb.net  dbName=untitled-combat-game-test environment=test port=4000 jest --config jestconfig.json"
```

My test file:

```
import { runServer } from "../index";

beforeAll(async () => {
  const serverOptions = {
    dbUrl: process.env.dbUrl,
    dbName: process.env.dbName,
    environment: process.env.environment,
    port: process.env.port
  };

  console.log(serverOptions);

  await runServer({
    ...serverOptions
  });
});

describe("mock test", () => {
  it("should run a basic test", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

What happens when I run the test:

- the test script runs `runServer`
- the index.js file runs `runServer`

This causes a invalid URI error (since the `process.argv` referenced in index.js does not include a valid mongodb URI). I double-checked this by commenting out the `runServer` call at the bottom of my index.js file - and everything runs fine.

Moving the `runServer` function to a different file and importing it from there also solves the issue. So importing in both index.js and the test file does not result in multiple calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing/requiring a file evaluates the code inside of it (read: *runs the code inside of it*). You're not technically doing anything wrong, but for the purpose of your tests the code as you have written it won't work.

In your `index.js` file you are executing `runServer()`. Whenever that file is imported/required, that function call is also run.

Having a `start.js` file or similar which will actually start your server is a common pattern. This will help you avoid the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the definition of your server and invoking your server into two different files, say `server.js` and `index.js`. I will leave the fixing up of the imports to you, but this is the idea:

**server.js**

```
// connect mongoDb, seed data if needed, run fastify server
export const runServer = async ({ dbUrl, dbName, environment, port }) => {
  // test seed data when starting server if running a test suite
  if (environment === "test") {
    await seedData({
      hostUrl: dbUrl,
      databaseName: dbName
    });
  }

  await MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, {
    poolSize: 50,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    wtimeout: 2500
  })
    .then(async conn => {
      const database = await conn.db(dbName);
      // inject database connection into DAO objects
      CharacterDAO.injectDB(database);
      GearDAO.injectDB(database);
      // start the fastify server
      startServer(port);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.stack);
      // process.exit(1);
    });
};
```

**index.js**

```
import { runServer } from './server';

const serverArguments = process.argv.slice(2).map(arg => {
  return arg.split("=")[1];
});

const serverOptions = {
  dbUrl: serverArguments[0],
  dbName: serverArguments[1],
  environment: serverArguments[2],
  port: serverArguments[3]
};

runServer({
  ...serverOptions
});
```

Comment: Just did that and it works - but I do not understand why would just importing from a file also invoke all the calls in that file. Is this a known js thing I just never ran into before?

Comment: Is this a known js thing I just never ran into before? Yes.